# Animate jQuery chart by changing rel on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to modify a jQuery knob plugin to use as an animated chart.

This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<ul id="chart">
<li rel="100">Cats</li>
```

```
<input class="knob animated donut" value="0" rel="70" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('.knob').each(function () {
var $this = $(this);
var myVal = $this.attr("rel");
$(this).knob({
    readOnly: true,
    displayInput: false,
    bgColor: "cccccc",
    fgColor: "e60022"
});
       $({
           value: 0
       }).animate({

           value: myVal
       }, {
           duration: 1000,
           easing: 'swing',
           step: function () {
               $this.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');

           }
       })
   });

$('#chart > li').mouseover(function(){    
    $('#donut').text($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

I'd like to be able to hover over the `<li>` element and use the `rel` value to apply it to the chart. I think I might need to include some JS to redraw the chart on hover though as well, but not sure how to do that either (I don't have much JS knowledge).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/pMJmF/27/ ??

Comment: @RobertRozas that doesn’t do anything for me?

Comment: On Line 26 of the JavaScript code in Robert Rozas' example, changing `$('#donut')` to `$('.donut')` seems to make it work but not `onmouseover`.

Comment: @DanielGulliver Ah yes I see the mistake there. Any ideas on how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/xx2Ky/)

You need to set the animate properties in the event handler. So, initialize your "knob" element as you did, then in the event handler retrieve the values and run the animation.

In the demo I used a data attribute (it just makes more sense to me), not the rel attribute, but the following should work with your markup:

```
var donut = $('.knob');    
donut.knob({readOnly: true,
    displayInput: false,
});
$('#chart > li').on('mouseenter', function(){    
    var myVal = $(this).attr('rel'); 
    donut.stop().animate({value: myVal}, {
           duration: 200,
           easing: 'swing',
           step: function () {
               donut.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
           }
    });
});
```

**HTML:** change the input to use the data attributes for color, as there is a bug in FF

```
<input class="knob" data-fgColor="#e60022" data-bgColor="#ccc" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The only issue I'm having is that it's really slow once I add a few more values. Any suggestions on how to improve speed? http://jsfiddle.net/xx2Ky/3/

Comment: It's not that it's getting slow per se.  It's that the overall difference in values between each change is smaller, but the duration over which it animates is unchanged.  Think of it this way: animating from 0-100 (360 degrees) over 1000ms is going to look a lot faster than 0-10 (36 degrees) over 1000ms.  You can definitely reduce the duration to help (try 200 instead). For more improvement you could: vary the duration based on the percent of change; always reset to 0 before changing the value; or add another visual queue like the displayInput that tricks the eye into seeing more movement.

Comment: Here's an example using all of the concepts I described above: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/xx2Ky/5/ Notice how much "faster" and more responsive it seems, yet the value changes are sometimes even less than 10.

Comment: Heads up!!! I'm on a MAC and I just noticed that there's a bug in the plugin (not my code).  When testing on Firefox, if you specify the color values in the initialization options it fails completely.  Also, I thought it was weird that on Chrome and Safari, the foreground color wasn't being applied correctly to the input value.  I strongly advise that you set the colors in the markup instead like this: <input class="dial" data-fgColor="#e60022" data-bgColor="#ccc" value="" />.  I updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/xx2Ky/6/  This now works reliably in all of my browsers.

Comment: Perfect. Is there anyway to make it cancel any active animation on mouse out? It seems to keep going if you run your mouse over multiple `<li>`s which looks a little buggy. Thanks so much you are a godsend!

Comment: Yes, you can use the jQuery .stop() method.  I updated this fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/xx2Ky/.  However, I put it at the beginning of the mouseenter and the reason for that is, if you do it in the mouseleave event, it will stop at whatever position the animation is which could be incorrect.  Make sense?  Also, if you found my answer(s) correct and helpful, please mark the answer to close it and upvote it for helpfulness.